# Local Toast notification from code

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to show a toast notification locally from code, without using a web service?

I would like to show a toast notification invoked from a DispatcherTimer.Tick only when the app is running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Coding4Fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) has a toast prompt that fits your needs. [This article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Toast-Prompt-in-depth) describes how to use it.